# Как отправить приватное сообщение пользователю с момощью Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api

Я пишу бота и не могу понять, как с его помощью сделать отправку приватных сообщений пользователю, после того как он подключился к серверу.

Само подключение к серверу, я так понимаю, можно отлавливать так:

```
const robot = new Discord.Client();
robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) =>
{
    gMembAdd.guild.channels.find("name", "test").sendMessage(gMembAdd.toString() + "hello people");
});
```

Сообщения в канал общего чата под названием "test" поступают, но не могу сделать отправку сообщений по приват-каналу отдельному пользователю. Пробовал так:

```
 robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) =>
    {
        gMembAdd.mentions.users.first().sendMessage(message.content.slice(4)); 
        gMembAdd.guild.channels.find("name", "test").sendMessage(gMembAdd.toString() + "hello people");
    });
```

Но код выдает ошибку.

Пробовал и так:

```
robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) =>
    {
        let ment = new Discord.Message();
        ment.mentions.users.first().sendMessage(message.content.slice(4)); 
        gMembAdd.guild.channels.find("name", "test").sendMessage(gMembAdd.toString() + "hello people");
    });
```

Пробовал еще и так:

```
robot.mentions.users.first().sendMessage(message.content.slice(4));
```

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, а точнее задал его на англоязычном сообществе, опубликую здесь возможно кому-то поможет. 
И так для начала как мне подсказали нужно отказаться от `.sendMessage` так как он устарел в новых версиях `Discord-api`, вместо этого нужно использовать `.send()`.
Так же когда вы подписываетесь на `guildMemberAdd` вы получаете [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) что позволяет напрямую отправлять сообщения:

```
robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) => {
    gMembAdd.guild.channels.find("name", "test").send(gMembAdd.toString() + "hello guys");
    gMembAdd.send("Test");
});
```